# How to pass Request cookies through node-fetch in isomorphic app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to build isomorphic project using React, Express and isomorphic fetch (based on `whatwg-fetch` on client and `node-fetch` on server), from [this](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) common boilerplate. I'm using cookies for my access token, and `credentials: 'same-origin'` on front-end side [to send it](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) to GraphQL -- works pretty well.

The problem is that I can't use the same solution for server side -- `node-fetch` just don't support using of XMLHttpRequest cookies from the box. My fetch request is under few abstract layers from router, so I can't just use cookie value from `req`.

Here is my `server.js` code ([full version](https://gist.github.com/be8dbc8fc688f6cd774d68ae92182fe4)):

```
server.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // some presettings here..

    await Router.dispatch({ path: req.path, query: req.query, context }, (state, component) => {
      data.body = ReactDOM.renderToString(component);
    });

    res.send(template(data));
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

and Route's `index.js` ([full version](https://gist.github.com/a55c83b42218e3e079ee0ae5d36cd2e6)):

```
export const action = async (state) => {
  const response = await fetch('/graphql?query={me{id,email}}', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  });
  const { data } = await response.json();
  // ...
  return <Login title={title} me={data.me} />;
};
```

How can I pass my token from server.js to my fetch module? Or, maybe there are some better decisions?

Comment: @Buzinas not yet, but get good feedback from Konstantin, React Starter Kit maintainer -- https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/554
Am going to solve it next days and public solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I hope you have found an answer by now!

Secondly, cookies are really just headers. If you *need* to send a cookie to authorize server-side requests, you can always just create the string that you need for the cookie value and send it as a header.

For an example, take a look at how this server-side `node-fetch` wrapper appends saved cookies to the outbound request: https://github.com/valeriangalliat/fetch-cookie/blob/master/index.js#L17